# SQL relaX error il18n is not defined. Trying to find Students (IDs and names) along with info about courses (course_ids) they took more than 1 time

Tags: sql

I am using the Silberschatz - UniversityDB gist f03130d8e6a7f0a9bcba3190fee1f0a8 with the relaX calulator.
[image]

This is the problem I am having. I am not sure what this error means when using the relaX relational algebra calulator, all of the problems I have seen with this error is related to web design. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the query editor is having some problems with `having` clause.
Try to use subquery and it will work ok.
Like `SELECT ID, name, course_id, times 
FROM
(
SELECT s.ID, s.name, t.course_id, COUNT(t.course_id) as times  FROM student as s
INNER JOIN takes as t ON t.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN course as c ON c.course_id = t.course_id
GROUP BY s.ID, s.name, t.course_id
) as temp
WHERE times > 1`

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this and see if I can get what I need.

Comment: What database platform are you using - SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc? Add that tag.

Comment: https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/landing There is no tag for the relaX platform and my rep is too low to create a new tag. But stated in the title.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your query.

1. You select from `student` and `course`, but mention a table or view called `takes` in the `ON` clause.
2. You group by `course_id` (so as to get one result row per course), but select `student.id`, `student.name` and `takes.course_id`. This is invalid, because there can be multiple students per course, so which one to select for the group? You would need aggreation functions to select student data (e.g. `MAX(student.id)` for the highest student ID). And again: there is no table `takes` in your from clause.
3. You are trying to create an alias in `GROUP BY` which is not allowed.

The error message `i18n is not defined` doesn't seem to make any sense here, though. Well, fix your errors and maybe you get thus rid of the strange message, too. Maybe the app is just trying to give you an error message in your language and fails to do so for some internal error with internationalization (which is what i18n stands for).